# Use robocopy to copy without attributes for files and directories

Tags: windows, ntfs, robocopy, file-attributes

I'm trying to run robocopy to copy data but not copying attributes (timestamps are ok).

My first thought was to run with these switches: /copy:dt /dcopy:t

The way I interpret the documentation, those switches should copy only the timestamps and data, not the attributes. And yet, when I run robocopy with those switches, the attributes are copied.

I also tried using /A-:RASHN. it removes attributes from files, but not directories.

Does anyone know how to run robocopy without copying attributes for both files and directories?

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). Why do you want to remove the attributes?

Comment: I want to back everything up as a normal file, so that hidden files don't scare people into thinking they lost data :-)

Comment: So use robocopy as normal and afterwards remove the hidden attributes.